# How to navigate to the right folder in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I am working on a gulp script, and I need to set up a path to a specific folder.

I am using this code:

```
var path = require("path")
var base = path.resolve('../'); // C:\Users\x\a\b\c\d
```

I need the result of base as:

```
 C:\Users\x\a
```

I am trying using `../../../` but with no success.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Maybe `path.resolve('../../../ + __dirname');` ?

Comment: @Lauromine I made an edit to my question thanks for taking your time on this.

Comment: it seems that path.resolve(__dirname + '../../../'); does the trick, any better way to achieve it?

Comment: where is this script relative to the Users Folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
`path.dirname(require.main.filename)`

It gives the absolute path to the directory of your project